# How were the zooming sequences performed?

Tags: film-techniques, limitless

In [**Limitless**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1219289/), one of the initial scenes features a unique [**zooming**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zqOVk9YRAo) effect that is a rare find.

How was this achieved and do these scenes serve any purpose story-wise or meant as a simple mind trip to generate the feel of the movie?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Limitless even opens with such a [seemingly endless zoom shot](http://www.techhive.com/article/223108/limitless_infinite_zoom.html) better know as **Fractal zoom**, though the scene you referred to, is not endless, but is more of a fly-by zoom shot. Such effects are often rendered by processing normal footage (using cameras) using advanced video editing software (like Adobe After Effects) or customized code to render fractal zoom.

This [interview here](http://www.techhive.com/article/223108/limitless_infinite_zoom.html) discusses in detail about the technology, technique and idea behind that opening shot for Limitless.

The article referred to, above says this about the software used

> PCW: What kind of software did your team use for the effects?
>
> Comen: The primary software we used was [The Foundry] Nuke for the
>   compositing, [Adobe] After Effects for the titles, and Maya for the 3D
>   graphics. Our team was a crew of about 20 people, including support
>   staff.

Another example of a really long fractal zoom can be found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&v=0jGaio87u3A) on YouTube. This video, took 6 months to render!